# Having trouble with Font Awesome display?

Tags: css

I don't know why my font awesome is coming as F105. I have checked the library. It's being called correctly. Help will be immensely appreciated.

The blog in mention is http://www.interactiveworld.in/search-engine-optimization/seo-audit-factors-a-checklist.html ... f105 appears on the right panel.

I am also having trouble with my footer menu. All menu items seem to be glued to one another. I can really do with some help. Have been struggling for more than a day now.

Comment: Can you please show your code.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with no code reference?

Comment: Sorry about this. The css for footer menu is .widget_nav_menu ul li  {float:left; margin-right:15px; }

Comment: Thank you Robert for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `aside .widget li:after { }` content declaration to be:

`content: '\f105';`

You're missing the slash.